# How to create a custom output/report format for boost unit test?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

How can a custom report format for boost unit test be created?

I'm looking at the docs, and am only able to find bits and pieces, it's unclear how it all fits together. I think I want a `unit_test_log_formatter`, but aren't sure how to add it. Or maybe I want a `test_observer`, but not sure how to add those either.

I really just want a summary of errors at the end of my test output. There is far too much output in the normal reports and I'm left hunting for errors in the output.

Comment: That's propably better asked at the boost user mailing list.

Comment: Someone needs to hang their head in embarassment. Fancy writing an entire testing framework, to then not provide a simple summary of test failures!

Comment: @user997112 You can also check the premise. In my experience the summaries are excellent at low report detail levels